# Spring Configuration Server: Fallback configuration in case repository is not available

Tags: spring, svn, server, fallback, spring-cloud-config

We use spring cloud configuration Server (SCCS) with a svn backend.
I currently investigate into fallback/emergency scenarios when the backend is (temporarly) not available.

In case of a svn backend SCCS is downloading the configuration files into a local directory.

Our idea is to configure SCCS it first looks for the svn backend, and when it is not available the copied files are taken for the source.

Does anybody know how configuration has to look like, or has a totally different idea how this scenario is to be faced?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want the Cloud Config Server to have multiple repositories. You can do that with profiles, but the switch from one repository to another one won't be automatic (at least from the top of my head).

- The Spring Cloud Config Server bootstrap.yml with two repositories:

`spring:
   profiles.active: remote-svn
   application:
     name: config-server
   cloud:
     config:
       server:
         svn:
            uri: https://yourserver.com/config-repo
            force-pull: true
//---
spring:
  profiles: local-svn
  application:
      name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        svn:
          uri: ${user.home}/config-repo`

Generally you would start your server like:

`mvn spring-boot:run`

But if your remote svn server is down, you would kill the server and restart it like:

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local-svn`

The thing is that you must maintain both of these repositories synced. So when you push your configurations to the SVN repository, you need to have two remotes configured. One referencing your SVN server and the other referencing the Spring Cloud Config Server repository.

You can have a bash script with a logic that checks the health of your SVN server and when it finds out that the server is down it restart the Spring Cloud Config Server using the local-svn profile.